# The service "SomthingContoller" has a dependency on a non-existent service "Swag\PluginName\Service\OrderService"

Tags: php, symfony, service, shopware, shopware6

I'm trying to make a custom api endpoint in shopware 6 to get an order details as according to the order Id but when i add some service to the controller its shows non-existent service even when i add those service which are passed to constructor as argument in service.xml.

**What are the reasons behind getting this error ?**

My files;

**src/Storefront/Controller/SomethingController.php**

```
    <?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Swag\PluginName\Storefront\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Swag\PluginName\Service\OrderService;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Context;

/**
 *
 * @Route(defaults={"_routeScope"={"api"}})
 */
class SomethingController extends AbstractController
{
    public $orderService;

    public function __construct(
        OrderService $orderService
    )
    {
        $this->orderService = $orderService;
    }

    /**
    * @Route("/api/orderconfig/{orderId}", name="api.something.orderconfig", methods={"GET"})
    * @param string $orderId
    * @return JsonResponse
    */
    public function orderConfig(string $orderId): JsonResponse
    {
        $order = $this->orderService->getOrder($orderId, Context::createDefaultContext());
        return $order;
    }


}
```

**src/Service/OrderService.php**

```
<?php

namespace Swag\PluginName\Service;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepositoryInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Order\OrderEntity;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Context;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Filter\EqualsFilter;

class OrderService
{
    /**
     * @var EntityRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $orderRepository;


    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * OrderRepository Constructor
     * 
     * @param EntityRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        EntityRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $orderId
     * @param Context $context
     * @param array $associations
     * @return OrderEntity|null
     */
    public function getOrder(string $orderId, Context $context, array $associations = []): ?OrderEntity
    {
        $order = null;

        try {
            $criteria = new Criteria();
            $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('id', $orderId));

            /** @var OrderEntity $order */
            $order = $this->getOrderByCriteria($criteria, $context, $associations);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error($e->getMessage(), [$e]);
        }

        return $order;
    }

    public function getOrderByCriteria(Criteria $criteria, Context $context, array $associations = []): ?OrderEntity
    {
        foreach ($associations as $association) {
            $criteria->addAssociation($association);
        }
        return $this->orderRepository->search($criteria, $context)->first();
    }

    public function getOrderByOrderNumber(string $orderNumber, Context $context, array $associations = []): ?OrderEntity
    {
        $criteria = new Criteria();
        $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('orderNumber', $orderNumber));

        return $this->getOrderByCriteria($criteria, $context, $associations);
    }

    public function update(string $orderId, array $data, Context $context)
    {
        $data['id'] = $orderId;
        $this->orderRepository->update([$data], $context);
    }
}
```

****src/Resources/config/services.xml****

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>
        <service id="Swag\PluginName\Storefront\Controller\SomethingController" public="true">
            <argument type="service" id="Swag\PluginName\Service\OrderService"/>
            <call method="setContainer">
                <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
            </call>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

Comment: Do you have an entry in services.xml for your OrderService?  In general you need to define all services unless you are using autowire.  `bin/console debug:container OrderService` can help with trouble shooting.

Comment: How can I register my service? @Cerad

Comment: What is your `services.yaml` configuration ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're not using autowiring for your services, at least looking at your `services.xml`.
Therefore you're missing the service registration of your `OrderService`, so that you can use it as an argument for your controller.

This would in your case look like something like this:

```xml
<service id="Swag\PluginName\Service\OrderService">
    <argument type="service" id="order.repository"/>
    <argument type="service" id="logger"/>
</service>
```

You can read more about manually registering services in the Symfony documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#services-explicitly-configure-wire-services)